# Is this decent code for changing the "int" element into other value of "int" element without using "str" conversion, in python?

Tags: python, expression

I'm finding a concise way to change the int element value in list.

And my best concise code is below.
<Purpose : changing 'number 1' to 'number 3'>

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,1,1]
list(map(lambda x: 3 if x==1 else x, a))
```

Is this a decent one or how can I express it more logically in python?

Have a nice day!

Comment: `[3 if x==1 else x for x in a]`

Comment: where are you using string conversion? I dont understand your question

Comment: Hello juanpa, i omitted this. I intended Using str().replace(,) for each element in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a list comprehension with a conditional statement embedded:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,1,1]
a = [3 if i==1 else i for i in a]
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 3, 3]
```